# javascript doc.cellInitialize() is not a function error

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
    var table = tableToJson($('#tableinfo').get(0))
    var doc = new jsPDF('p','pt', 'a4', true);
    doc.cellInitialize();
    $.each(table, function (i, row){
        console.debug(row);
        $.each(row, function (j, cell){
            doc.cell(10, 50,120, 50, cell, i);  // 2nd parameter=top margin,1st=left margin 3rd=row cell width 4th=Row height
        })
    })
});
```

this code to convert html table to pdf format.
here i am getting doc.cellInitialize() is not a function error.can anyone help on this....

Comment: have you added the links of jsPDF scripts

Comment: have you checked the docs (http://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/index.html) or even the source to see if the method definitely exists and you've spelled it correctly?